# .update(params) also updates previous variables with its own query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, updatemodel

I'm have this code in model.

```
old_amounts = OldAmount.where(["amount_id = ?", self.id]).first
self.update!(old_amount_params)

new_amounts = OldAmount.where(["amount_id = ?", self.id]).first
```

I need the old_amounts to be compare with new_amounts but the `.update` triggers something that makes `old_amounts` as same as `new_amounts`.

for example in `old_amounts` its `101` then in new_amounts in would become 102, so the difference would be `102-101=1` right? I tried to `raise "#{old_amount}"` after `old_amounts` after `self.update(..)` the value of old_amount is also 102. So i can't check its difference.

Can someone can explain to me why is that?

Comment: before self.update what is old_amounts?

Comment: the old_amount.amount = 101

Comment: self.update_columns(column_name: value) try this method instead of update